# Regex search with wildcard and insert

Tags: regex

I have thousands of lines of code that need an adjustment:
Currently they look like this:

```
htmlentities($row_author['Book_ID'])
htmlentities($_GET['BookTitle'])
```

etc. For internationalization, I need them to include ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'

```
htmlentities($row_author['Book_ID'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8')
htmlentities($_GET['BookTitle'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8')
```

I have looked all morning for a regex that would let me search and insert the , ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8' part to the end of the existing code, but regex is 'through the looking glass' for me and I could use some pointers.

I used .* to find all of them, but the insert of the ENT_COMPAT is tricky.

Thank you for any help you can offer. The correct answer will be Checked.

Comment: Which language are you running?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Looks like php...

Comment: did you want to replace `htmlentities` line only?

Comment: Why do you want to program this? Simply use a decent code editor and use the Find&Replace feature.

Comment: I'm using PHP and Dreamweaver (no comments, please :-)) and the search and replace function lets me find them, but the replace, of course, overwrites the existing code with .*  How do I prevent that?

Comment: Don't use `htmlentities()` directly. In 2 months you'll need something else and have to redo everything again. Create a function that does the utf8 compat etc and use that function everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  (.*?\])
```

Try this.

Replacement string will include your added characters.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dD3nI1/1

Comment: Wow, that appears to have worked really well. Let me continue for a bit before I let you go... and thanks again.

Comment: Yes, vks, I added the htmlentites to the front of the $i and it worked like magic. Thank you very much. You saved me endless hours of tedium.

Comment: @vks no need to include the quantifier `?` because there is only one `]` symbol present on that line..

Comment: @vks may i now why are you using spaces before the code?

Comment: @vks many answers of your's have the preceding spaces. Please avoid that. Because your current regex looks like match two spaces and capture the characters following.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this recursive regex for search:

```
'^(\s*htmlentities\s*)( \( (?: [^()]* | (?2) )* \) )/mx'
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uQ8mB7/1)

#### CODE

```
$input = "htmlentities(trim(\$_GET['BookTitle']))";
$result = preg_replace_callback('/^(\s*htmlentities\s*)( \( (?: [^()]* | (?2) )* \) )/mx',
    function ($m) { return $m[1] . substr($m[2], 0, strrpos($m[2], ')')) .
       ', ENT_COMPAT, "utf-8")'; }, $input);
echo $result;
//=> htmlentities(trim($_GET['BookTitle']), ENT_COMPAT, "utf-8")
```

Comment: Thanks for the time you put in @anubhava. I'll look here if the answer from vks fails me along the way.

Comment: @AllThisOnAnACER: It took me little while to produce an example where other answer fail i.e. when `)` is already present in the input. [See this demo where accepted regex fails](http://regex101.com/r/dD3nI1/2) and as you can see from my answer it handles nested brackets also.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an editor, you need a search and replace:

```
Search:  htmlentities\(\$\w+\[.*?\]
Replace: $0, ENT_COMPAT, "utf-8"
```

Depending on your editor "$0" may need to be "\0".

Comment: Thanks guys. Vks nailed it. I appreciate your taking the time for me.